# How can I remove both index.php and ? from my urls that are coming in from indexed google search results?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have thousands of URLs indexed by Google from my old ecommerce system. I'm adding redirect rules on my new system, but none of them work as long as `index.php?` is in the URL.

I added these rules into my `.htaccess` file, but when I click on a URL on Google, it takes me to the homepage of my new site, and the `index.php?` is still in the URL.

Is there any way to have both the `index.php` and the `?` removed from an incoming URL?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What do you incoming URLs look like? "but none of them work as long as index.php? is in the url" - What do your redirects look like? This may just require a simple fix. Why is `index.php?` in the URL in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to turn this
`https://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=<id>`

into this `https://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=<id>`

This was what worked in the end

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (route.*)
RewriteRule "(.*)index.php" $1%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "needed to turn this ... into this" - but it's the same URL? I guess you mean, into this `/route=product/product&product_id=<id>` (moving the query string to the URL-path) - which would seem to be what those directives are doing (although these directives could be simplified). Presumably, you then issue a _second redirect_ to get to the user to where they are supposed to be going?

Comment: That's correct. These are links from Opencart 1.5, and they make no sense. I'm switching this client over to Magento 2, and that has an option to create url keys. I wrote a script that created thousands of records for the url rewrite table, but I had to make sure that when a request came via Google (or an old email campaign) that the new site would come up, and on the correct page. This was needed to make that happen, without it messing with my search plugin